# Where does Rails store model Attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created and run a migration, a model file exists, there is information in my schema.rb file - but where does Rails store data about my models?! When I run Model.new, obviously it knows what attributes my new model needs to have - but where does it get that information? What file is it stored in?

Comment: It's stored in the database. Upon starting up, rails connects to the database and reads metadata of the tables, inferring model attributes from those.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your model attributes doing this:

```
Model.column_names         
Model.columns_hash         
Model.columns
```

I recommend the use of the annotate gem -> https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models

Run a simple command after running migrations and you can get the current schema for each model

```
# == Schema Info
#
# Table name: line_items
#
#  id                  :integer(11)    not null, primary key
#  quantity            :integer(11)    not null
#  product_id          :integer(11)    not null
#  unit_price          :float
#  order_id            :integer(11)
# 

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  . . .
```